# How i can get the error when cake are saving?

Tags: cakephp, model, save, cakephp-2.0

I have a form, with some fields. When i try save, not happens and I don´t know what´s the problem.
How can i see whats happening on the save moment ?!

Thanks you!.

Answer (score 3):

These are the most likely causes for a failed save:

- incorrect data array structure, debug data passed for saving
- failing validation, debug($this->SomeModel->validationErrors) after save
- beforeSave/beforeValidate callback in model or attached behavior not returning true
- sql error, turn up debug to 2

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I managed to find all errors.

Answer (score 1):

Anywhere in your view file, you get the errors like this :

```
<?php debug($this->AnyModel->validationErrors);?>
```

Aside from debugging, you display field-by-field error like this :

```
<?php $this->Form->error('fieldname'); ?>
```

This will return the message from validation rules, only if the field has thrown an error.

Hope this helps!